# I can't use onClick Event in React

Tags: reactjs, events, datatable, onclick, treeview

I'm using react-data-table and I have to make folder-tree I made but I cant click to span in TreeNode Component. I don't know why.

```
<td>
                            <div className="special-card2">
                              <NetworkSharesTree data={row.original.data} />
                            </div>
                          </td>
```

```
import React from "react";
import { AiFillFolder, AiFillFile } from "react-icons/ai";
import { MdArrowDropDown, MdArrowRight } from "react-icons/md";
import FolderTree from "./FolderTree";
import { Tree } from "react-arborist";
const NetworkSharesTree = ({ data }) => {
  const filterDirectories = (data) => {
    const directoryArray = Object.values(data).filter(
      (obj) => obj.type === "directory"
    );
    return directoryArray;
  };
  let directories = filterDirectories(data);

  const convertToArboristFormat = (dataArray) => {
    const result = [];

    const iterateData = (items, parent = null) => {
      items.forEach((item, index) => {
        const newItem = {
          id: item.path
            ? item.path + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
            : item.name + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
          name: item.path ? item.path : item.name,
          children: item?.type === "directory" ? [] : null,
          //   isOpen: "true",
        };

        if (item.shares) {
          iterateData(item.shares, newItem);
        }

        if (parent) {
          parent.children.push(newItem);
        } else {
          result.push(newItem);
        }
      });
    };

    iterateData(dataArray);

    return result;
  };
  const arboristData = convertToArboristFormat(directories);

  return (
    <div>
      <FolderTree data={arboristData} />
      {/* <Tree initialData={arboristData} width="1000" openByDefault={false} /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NetworkSharesTree;
```

```
import React from "react";
import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";
const FolderTree = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((node) => (
        <TreeNode
          key={node.id + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}
          node={node}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FolderTree;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiFillFolder, AiOutlineFolder, AiFillFile } from "react-icons/ai";

const TreeNode = ({ node }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const hasChildren = node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{ marginLeft: hasChildren ? "16px" : "24px" }}
        onClick={handleToggle}
      >
        <span>
          {hasChildren ? (
            isOpen ? (
              <AiFillFolder color="#f6cf60" size={20} />
            ) : (
              <AiOutlineFolder color="#f6cf60" size={20} />
            )
          ) : (
            <AiFillFile color="#6bc7f6" />
          )}
        </span>
        <span style={{ marginLeft: "8px" }}>{node.name}</span>
      </div>
      {hasChildren && isOpen && (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "16px" }}>
          {node.children.map((child) => (
            <TreeNode key={child.id} node={child} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TreeNode;
```

You can see all code above. I tried out of table and it works well. When I copied inside of table, it doesn't work. If I don't use map func in FolderTree Component, I can click to span. But I have to use map func. When I used map function I can't click in TreeNode Component.

Comment: Please make a minimal example on codesandbox.io and paste a link here.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-meadow-8qlpyr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A12%2C1

İt works well here but , it doesnt work in my project. How can ı learn that why it dont work

Comment: You can either import the working code into your project and start changing it bit by bit until it doesn't work anymore, or you can try to turn the codesandbox code into your project code bit by bit until it doesn't work anymore there.
Unfortunately, it's hard to make a more specific recommendation if you cannot reproduce an example that shows the error.

Comment: I m working on a template. Can it be that  it doesnt work so ?

Comment: What do you mean with your last comment? I don't understand.